# Curl Command to Repeat URL Request

Tags: linux, url, curl

Whats the syntax for a linux command that hits a URL repeatedly, x number of times. I don't need to do anything with the data, I just need to replicate hitting refresh 20 times in a browser.

Answer (score 166):

You could use URL sequence substitution with a dummy query string (if you want to use CURL and save a few keystrokes):

```sh
curl http://www.myurl.com/?[1-20]
```

If you have other query strings in your URL, assign the sequence to a throwaway variable:

```sh
curl http://www.myurl.com/?myVar=111&fakeVar=[1-20]
```

Check out the URL section on the man page: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: Works for -X POST as well

Comment: Also adding --parallel and --parallel-max for simplistic concurrent calling

Comment: I can't find that syntax for sequence substitution. Has the command changed since this answer?

Comment: The manual link in the answer has a section called URL that talks about sequence usages. It’s worth mentioning that: “When using [] or {} sequences when invoked from a command line prompt, you probably have to put the full URL within double quotes to avoid the shell from interfering with it. This also goes for other characters treated special, like for example '&', '?' and '*'.”

Answer (score 108):

```bash
for i in `seq 1 20`; do curl http://url; done
```

Or if you want to get timing information back, use `ab`:

```
ab -n 20 http://url/
```

Comment: ok i knew that much.. turns out what i was missing is '' around the url since my url has parameters and the '&' messed up the command

Comment: use "Quotation mark" for URL. It's something like:

`for i in $(seq 1 20); do curl "http://url"; done`

Comment: Awesome. My two cents. Can use `n=20;for i in \`seq 1 $n\`;do (echo;echo Execution start $i;curl curl http://url; echo ;echo Execution End $i;); done</code>` to parameterize/add to a script and add header and footer.

Answer (score 93):

You might be interested in [Apache Bench](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/689.cfm) tool which is basically used to do simple load testing.

example  :

```
ab -n 500 -c 20 http://www.example.com/
```

> n = total number of request, c = number of concurrent request

Answer (score 8):

You can use any bash looping constructs like `FOR`, with is compatible with Linux and Mac.

https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs

In your specific case you can define `N` iterations, with `N` is a number defining how many `curl` executions you want.

```bash
for n in {1..N}; do curl <arguments>; done
```

ex:

```bash
for n in {1..20}; do curl -d @notification.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:3000/dispatcher/notify; done
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add an interval before executing the cron the next time you can add a sleep

> for i in `{1..100}`;  do echo $i && curl "http://URL" >> /tmp/output.log && sleep 120; done

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a bit of delay before each request you could use the `watch`command in Linux:

`watch curl https://yourdomain.com/page`

This will call your url every other second. Alter the interval by adding the ´-n´ parameter with a delay containing the number of seconds. For instance:

`watch -n0.5 curl https://yourdomain.com/page`

This will now call the url every half second.

CTRL+C to exit `watch`